# Grab and Split Content of a File and Use it as a variable in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to grab a list of servers from a file and grab the root drive as well.

This is the content of the file:

**serverlist.config**

```
WKS_LIST                           install  WKS1 WKS2 \
                                            WKS3 WKS4 WKS5 \
                                            WKS6

WKS_ROOT_PATHS                       install    C:\temp D:\temp \
                                                C:\temp C:\temp C:\temp \
                                                C:\temp


SERVER_LIST                       install   NODE0 NODE1 \
                                            APP1 APP2 APP3 \
                                            APP4 APP5 APP6 \
                                            APP7

SERVER_ROOT_PATHS              install          I:\temp E:\temp I:\temp \
                                            I:\temp I:\temp I:\temp \
                                            I:\temp I:\temp I:\temp \
                                            I:\temp

TEST_LIST                       install     TEST1 TEST2

TEST_ROOT_PATHS                 install     I:\temp I:\temp
```

I want the batch script to look through serverlist.config and get the variable to the following like this:

```
set serverlist=NODE0 NODE1 APP1 APP2 APP3 APP4 APP5 APP6 APP7
set rootpath=I E I I I I I I I I

FOR %%a in (%serverlist%) do robocopy \\%%a\%rootpath%$\temp\log I:\temp\TEST-LOG\%%a *mask1* *mask2* /S /copyall /maxage:20200227 /xd *mask3* >> I:\temp\output.log
```

Can you please provide assistance on how to grab and split the serverlist.config file to get them into the variable as noted above in the batch script?

Please let me know if you need anything.

Comment: I would advise that you do not consider batch files for trying to parse anything other than very basic text files. There are third party helper utilities which may assist you, but I'd suggest you to seek the assistance of a proper scripting language first.

Comment: I'm limited to what I can install on the workstation/servers so I can only use basic batch script.

Comment: There are already more advanced scripting languages built into your OS, Windows Script Host, _(VBScript, JScript)_, and PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "server_list=serverlist.config"

rem Set variables with leading underscores from the server list i.e. _SERVER_LIST=...
set "continuation="

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (!server_list!) do @(
    set "line=%%~A"

    if "!line:~-1!" == "\" (
        set "continuation=y"
        if defined last_line (
            set "line=!last_line! !line:~,-1!"
        ) else (
            set "line=!line:~,-1!"
        )
    ) else if defined continuation (
        set "continuation="
        set "line=!last_line! !line!"
        for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%B in ("!line!") do set "_%%~B=%%~D"
        set "line="
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%B in ("!line!") do set "_%%~B=%%~D"
        set "line="
    )

    set "last_line=!line!"
)

rem Set _SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES from _SERVER_ROOT_PATHS
set "_SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES="

for %%A in (!_SERVER_ROOT_PATHS!) do (
    set "drive=%%~dA"

    if defined drive (
        set "drive=!drive:~,1!"
        if defined _SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES (
            set "_SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES=!_SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES! !drive!"
        ) else (
            set "_SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES=!drive!"
        )
    )
)

rem Run robocopy (Remove echo and carets if looks OK to actually run robocopy)
for %%A in (%_SERVER_LIST%) do (
    echo robocopy \\%%A\!_SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES!$\temp\log I:\temp\TEST-LOG\%%A *mask1* *mask2* /S /copyall /maxage:20200227 /xd *mask3* ^>^> I:\temp\output.log
)
```

The `echo` output of the `robocopy` command matches the output from the code in the question.

The code will read the server list and will use keywords like `SERVER_LIST` and will prepend leading underscore to use as variable names. Values `set` to the variable names will be values on the same line and will include values on the next line, if a end of line continuation character `\` is detected.

Drives letters are extracted from `_SERVER_ROOT_PATHS` and are set to a new variable named `_SERVER_ROOT_DRIVES`.

The `robocopy` command will be echoed to the console for viewing to check if OK.

Can use `set _` to view the leading underscored variable names and values in the script for the need of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely inflexible, but works:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set config=serverlist.config

:a
set x=2
set y=2
for /f "tokens=1*" %%x in (%config%) do (
if "%%x" equ "SERVER_LIST" set x=0
if "%%x" equ "SERVER_ROOT_PATHS" (set x=1 & set y=0)
if "%%x" equ "TEST_LIST" goto :b
if !x! equ 0 echo %%x %%y>>serverlist.txt 
if !y! equ 0 echo %%x %%y>>rootpath.txt
)

:b
for /f "delims=\" %%x in (serverlist.txt) do set "SERVER_LIST=!SERVER_LIST!%%x"
for /f "tokens=3*" %%x in ("%SERVER_LIST%") do set "serverlist=%%x %%y"

:c
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (rootpath.txt) do (
set "paths=%%x"
for %%a in (: \ temp) do set "paths=!paths:%%a=!"
set "ROOT_PATH=!ROOT_PATH!!paths!"
)
for /f "tokens=3*" %%x in ("%ROOT_PATH%") do set "rootpath=%%x %%y"

:d
del serverlist.txt
del rootpath.txt
FOR %%a in (%serverlist%) do robocopy \\%%a\%rootpath%$\temp\log I:\temp\TEST-LOG\%%a *mask1* *mask2* /S /copyall /maxage:20200227 /xd *mask3* >> I:\temp\output.log
ENDLOCAL
```

Basically it grabs the content between:

1. `SERVER_LIST` and `SERVER_ROOT_PATHS`
2. `SERVER_ROOT_PATHS` and `TEST_LIST`

Comment: Thanks @HackingAddict0302
If there is no TEST_LIST and TEST_ROOT_PATHS, how would it work?
Is there way to exit out of that and still make the script work?